# What do you say about a person who is a higher rank than a hobbyist?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What do you say about someone who does something as a hobby, but has higher knowledge than others and can transfer his/her hobby into a profession?

Example sentence: "Adam has superior knowledge about coffee. He's a ____"

I thought about **Expert** or **Professional**, but they feel too high on the spectrum.

Comment: enthusiast or amateur or neophyte

Comment: A craftsperson or artisan, maybe. Or specialist.

Comment: In Photography we would say "serious amateur", or possibly "serious enthusiast"

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I edited your Q to include the tag "phrase-requests". If you do not like it you can always "roll-back"

Comment: Good answers, they go below

Answer (score 1):

**connoisseur**

a person who is especially competent to pass critical judgments in an art, particularly one of the fine arts, or in matters of taste:

a connoisseur of modern art.

a discerning judge of the best in any field:

a connoisseur of horses.

**aficionado**

an ardent devotee; fan, enthusiast.

www.dictionary.com

Comment: Bravo and +1...I was just on the point of publishing _aficionado_.